# Long click doesn't work (using push down to refresh library)

Tags: android, push

Since I am using chrisbanes [push down to refresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) library, I had to remove normal listview and replace it with the new one. After that though, long push on listview item doesn't work and always creashes. It seems that info returns always null, as he doesn't get information, what I am actually clicking, which is bad. Have been trying to fix it myself, but with no success.. Any help is appreciated.

xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loadingbar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/loading_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Loading... Hang in there!"
    android:visibility="gone" />

 <com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
android:id="@+id/animelist"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

and the longpush code:

```
/** This will be invoked when an item in the listview is long pressed */
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

        Log.d("readInfo", "LONG CLICK!!"); 
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        Log.d("prereadlongclickinfo", "test"); 
        favorites = readFavoritesList();
        parsedFavorites = parse(favorites);
        Log.d("readlongclickinfo", "test2"); 
        Log.d("readlongclickinfo", "test: "); 

        /*boolean favorited = false;
        for(String favorite : parsedFavorites){
            if(favorite.equals(anime_list.get(info.position).seriaal)){
                menu.add(0, 2, 1, R.string.removeFavorite);
                favorited = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!favorited) {
            menu.add(0, 1, 1, R.string.addFavorite);
            menu.add(0, 3, 1, R.string.addBlacklist);
        }*/
        menu.add(0, 4, 1, R.string.openWebpage);
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }
```

Also, I am using custom adapter, where I store all the information regarding every listitem row item, which I need to use in longpush.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sad that nobody helped.

Well, after doing hours of research, I found solution, what was ridiculously easy. I hope it will guide people who are having same problem in future.

Basically, I made empty ListView and and gave it all the values what my pushDownListView had. After that, I registered it for create function. Few lines of codes:

```
pullToRefreshView = (PullToRefreshListView) findViewById(R.id.animelist);
        ListView lv1 = pullToRefreshView.getRefreshableView();

    registerForContextMenu(lv1);

    lv1.setAdapter(anime_list_adapter);

    registerForContextMenu(lv1);
```